# Laravel 5.3 Undefined index: sendmail

Tags: php, email, laravel-5.3

**The Full Error**

> ErrorException in TransportManager.php line 69:
>   Undefined index: sendmail

**The Scenario**

Im trying to send an email from my Laravel application online, for some reason its not working and all I'm getting is the above error.

**The Code**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.live.com
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Everything else in my laravel `config/mail.php` directory has been left as default.

Any help or insight would be great thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this to your `config/mail.php`:

```
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs'
```

You might have to adjust the path depending on your OS.